# How to redirect to component on click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to redirect to another component when the user clicks on a button like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Article from '../Article/Article.js'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'


const Posts = ({ posts, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <div class="loader">
           <div class="spinner"></div>
           </div>
  }


  return (
    <Router>
     <div className="post-container">
         {posts.map(post => (
        <div key={post._id} className='post'>
          <img className="post-container__image" src={post.picture} alt="image"/>
            <div className="post-container__post">
              <div className="post-container__text">
                <h2 className="post-container__title">{post.title}</h2>
                <p className="post-container__date">{post.date}</p>
                <p className="post-info-container__text">{post.postContent.substring(0, 500) + "..."}</p>
                <button className="read-more-btn" onClick={() => () => <Route path="/article" component={Article}/>}>Read more</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      ))}
     </div>
     </Router>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

But currently when the user clicks on the button nothing happens, how can I achieve the redirection to the desired component?

Comment: it may help you https://codesandbox.io/s/so-58629148-k34rd ?

Comment: That's not how `react-router` works. You should use a `<Switch>` and `<Link>`. The first result when googling "react router" has the answer you need: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 1):

you can use `props.history.push();` or `Router.push();` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic routing is supported in `react-router`; there's no need to render a new component. (By the way, that onClick is supposed to do something, right now it just returns a callback that returns a react component, which makes no sense since the `onClick` isn't supposed to even have a return value!)

I also don't know why you wrap one component in a router. You should have a single router at the top level of your app that contains each of the individual routes.

Assuming you put the posts component in a router component somewhere else in your app:

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


const Posts = withRouter(({ history, posts, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <div class="loader">
           <div class="spinner"></div>
           </div>
  }

  // Removed the <Router> component because it can't route to anything else properly that way. 
  // Have every component in your app be in a single router at the top level.
  return (
     <div className="post-container">
         {posts.map(post => (
        <div key={post._id} className='post'>
          <img className="post-container__image" src={post.picture} alt="image"/>
            <div className="post-container__post">
              <div className="post-container__text">
                <h2 className="post-container__title">{post.title}</h2>
                <p className="post-container__date">{post.date}</p>
                <p className="post-info-container__text">{post.postContent.substring(0, 500) + "..."}</p>
                <button className="read-more-btn" onClick={() => history.push('/article')}>Read more</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      ))}
     </div>
  );
});

export default Posts;
```

The `history` prop is provided to components using `withRouter` and can be used to go to a new location with `push` or `replace`. It's based on the [history NPM package](https://npmjs.com/package/history).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<Link>` to redirect.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Posts = ({ posts, loading }) => {
 if (loading) {
    return <div class="loader">
           <div class="spinner"></div>
           </div>
  }

  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/article" component={Article}/>
      <div className="post-container">
        <Link
          className="read-more-btn"  // give button's css to link
          to='/article'              // redirect
        >
          Read more
        </Link>
      </div>
     </Router>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

**Note:-** In your case you can not use history.push() to redirect the component because while using history prop you need to bind your component like `withRouter(YourComponent)` and in your code it will give you error like `"You should not use <withRouter(YourComponent) /> outside a <Router>"`. If you want to use history.push() then you need to separate both file one for routes and one for redirect file.